# javascript and asp.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am going to be doing a lot more front end work on one of our asp.net projects and I suspect there will be a lot more JavaScript involved. I have seen and used a lot of tutorials/info on the fundamentals of the JavaScript language but could someone point me towards some resources on JavaScript specifically for using it with asp.net? If specific tutorials/pages don't really exist then maybe some of the methods,tools,libraries etc. you would use and are worth reading about?

Comment: @Ashley John, that's *horrible* advice for anyone new to JavaScript. It's certainly a good library, but it's **not** a good way to learn to program JS.

Comment: ++zzzzBov; I'm very saddened by the sudden influx of incapable web developers, made worse by a reliance on jQuery, which is completely unnecessary in most situations that it is used in anyway.

Comment: You must understand first that JavaScript and ASP.NET are totally independent from each other, each and its own uses and syntax. You won't find "resources on JavaScript specifically for using it with asp.net" because it's simply not relevant.

Comment: @zzzzBov is asp.net a good way to learn html? Maybe we should tell him to scrap that too

Comment: @shiznit123, if the question had been: `I'm looking to start web development and I've read a few tutorials, what are some good resources for learning more?` I would ***not*** say ASP.NET because it *isn't* a good way to learn HTML. The question was about learning more JavaScript, not about how to shortcut many of the faults in the language. It's important to have a good understanding of the faults of the language so that you can make good use of the tools available, such as jQuery.

Comment: @Shadow Wizard, that is definetly not true. ASP.NET AJAX offers a LOT of stuff client-side, that is also available on server-side. One great and often ignored and/or undervalued thing is i.e. the Culture information as well as most server-side available string operations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are some general resources to get you started - for some specifics of JavaScript vis-a-vis ASP.NET, see last two links:

[JavaScript in Ten Minutes](https://github.com/spencertipping/js-in-ten-minutes/raw/master/js-in-ten-minutes.pdf) (PDF)

[JavaScript Garden](http://bonsaiden.github.com/JavaScript-Garden/)

[Basic JavaScript](http://elegantcode.com/2011/02/15/basic-javascript-part-10-the-module-pattern/)

[Eloquent JavaScript](http://eloquentjavascript.net/)

[The Essentials of Writing High Quality JavaScript](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/the-essentials-of-writing-high-quality-javascript/)

[Learn JavaScript, straight from the Gurus - Free JavaScript Video Lectures](http://www.devcurry.com/2010/09/learn-javascript-straight-from-gurus.html)

[24 JavaScript Best Practices for Beginners](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/24-javascript-best-practices-for-beginners/)

[Calling JavaScript from ASP.NET Master Page and Content Pages](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=274)

[Injecting Client-Side Script from an ASP.NET Server Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa478975.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Remember, that ASP.NET is (mostly) a server-side technology, and what it produces is simply HTML. So there's nothing really specifc to using javascript with ASP.NET.

What you should do, is to study and understand the HTML which is produced by the ASP.NET controls.

One important point is that the server-side control IDs do not correspond with the client-side IDs of the HTML element. E.g. you'll have to do things like this:

```
//aspx:
<asp:HyperLink id="myLink" ... />

//javascript:
var clientId = '<%= myLink.ClientID %>';
// access the client-side element using plain javascript and jQuery:
var linkJs = document.getElementById(clientId);
var linkJq = $('#' + clientId);
```

Comment: BTW: in addition to the above, I would also suggest to look at jQuery since it seems to be the "de-facto standard" javascript library in ASP.NET world, and it's also supported by microsoft.

Comment: .NET 4.0 allows you to control the client id much more than previous versions. So for simple pages, you can make sure that the .net control does match the id

Comment: @Tim: that's true, but usually you cannot use static IDs (e.g. when using repeaters, grids, etc. or when using multiple instances of the same user controls on a page).

Comment: Also, this is very good advice about the HTML which is rendered. Some people do not understand that asp.net renders HTML, pure and simple. Sometimes the HTML that is rendered is crap! but it is still just HTML.

Comment: Nothing specific to ASP.NET? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479011.aspx

Comment: @IrishChieftain: that article is from 2004 - I wouldn't take that as a reference of how to use javascript in a web app.

Comment: (Bad example, but...) Just making the point that there are a host of JavaScript-specific things with ASP.NET (see last two links in my answer). How about methods for registering his scripts for example? :)

Answer (score 1):

- [*Javascript: The Definitive Guide, Third Edition* by David Flanagan](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9781565923928)
- [*JavaScript: The Good Parts* by Douglas Crockford](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596517748)

Comment: "The Good Parts" should be mandatory reading before doing JS development.  Learning the parts of the language that are terrible (and avoidable) will pay huge dividends when it comes to debugging and maintaining your code later.

Comment: How do these resources relate to asp.net?

Comment: As many others have stated, JavaScript never relates to ASP.NET.

Comment: @Delan, built right, JS and ASP.NET can fit together like a hand in a glove.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to learn jquery which will make your life a lot easier. Another thing to keep in mind is that it doesn't really matter whether you are using asp.net or php or any other framework because javascript and associated libraries like jquery use HTML DOM objects and work on the client side.

A good book to learn jquery is Jquery in Action

Answer (score -2):

EDITED:

W3Schools is NOT good for the basics of JavaScript

Once you get to grips with JavaScript you may find JQuery useful. Its a very neat and useful JavaScript Library

http://jquery.com/

Comment: No! W3schools is frequently incorrect, and encourages bad programming practices. For a detailed explanation, see http://w3fools.com